# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

i have problem with PermissionError: [WinError 5] permission denied. Can somebody tell my why?

```
import subprocess

run_shell = subprocess.run(['./', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

test = str(run_shell.stdout.decode()).split('\n')

for el in test:
    if not el:
        continue
    print(f"Plik: {el}")
print("Info: {}".format(run_shell.stderr.decode()))
```

Even if i am trying only with subprocess, I still have it.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['./', 'ls'])
```

tried this, doesn't help.

```
subprocess.run([r'./', 'ls'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gawiq\KodyPython\lekcja_5_8.py", line 4, in <module>
    run_shell = subprocess.run(['./', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\gawiq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\gawiq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\gawiq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Permission denied
PS C:\Users\gawiq\KodyPython>
```

I tried already in CLI with administrator rights:
pip install pydirectory,
python -m pip install --upgrade pip,

also i tried

pip install --user subprocess.run,

but then, i got this:

```
Python: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Python version 3.10.5
pip version-22.2.1
using Windows 10 Home 64-bit and VSC

Thanks for help!

Comment: `subprocess.run(['./', 'ls'])` The first item in the list is the name of the command.  You're trying to run a command named `./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that neither `ls`  nor `./` is avalid command for the Windows CLI

Comment: yes, also probles was in sequence, i changed it to ['dir', 'C:\\Users\\gawiq\\KodyPython'] and now it works. Thanks!